# (Dis)prove that this system of inequalities has only $(0, 0, 0)$ as a solution

Tags: inequality

Consider the following system of inequalities:

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
\beta^2 + 4\gamma\theta \geq 0 \\
\theta^2 + 4\gamma\beta \geq 0 \\
\gamma^2 + 4\theta\beta \geq 0 
\end{array}
\right.
$$

such that $\theta, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}$.

Prove or disprove that the only solution to these is $(0, 0, 0)$.

I considered adding up the inequalities so that a large number of terms can be grouped together as a perfect square:

$$(\beta + \theta + \gamma)^2 + 2\gamma\theta + 2\gamma\beta + 2\theta\beta \geq 0$$

But even if we were able to somehow group the last three terms as a perfect square, we would be no better off since both will be $\geq 0$.

I need this proof to solve another problem, so I'm pretty certain the conjecture is true.

Comment: Just an unrelated question: why that choice of variables, which are slightly harder to read and much harder to type with LaTeX? What's wrong with $\;a,b,c$ ?

Comment: Are those unknowns related somehow? For example, are they the roots of some polynomial or stuff?

Comment: Doesn't any triple of nonnegative numbers satisfy these simultaneously?

Comment: Why not look for a counterexample? $(1,1,1)$ seems to work fine.

Comment: @DonAntonio: This was actually because in the question I was doing, I had already used $a, b, c, \alpha$. I used $\beta, \theta, \gamma$ to avoid confusion.

Comment: Doesn't any triple of negative numbers satisfy these too?

Comment: Are you sure that the inequalities are all $\ge 0$ and not all $\le 0$?